# Dynamically created inputs with if else checkbox and multiple field validation

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks add more options, a from is created with javascript `document.getElementById('addmore').innerHTML`... It works great to display the form multiple times. I added a unique number each time to create unique IDs for each of the fields for submission. I have a checkbox that, if checked, needs to display another fields to get filled out:

```
document.getElementById('addmore').innerHTML += '<p><div class="required">*Type of Folder</div><label for="it09" class="hidelabel">Content Drive</label><input name="request['+fields+'][Type of Folder:]" id="cbpathCDB'+fields+'" type="checkbox" value="Content Drive" class="required" /><strong>Content Drive</strong> (A: drive)<br /><div id="pathCDB'+fields+'"><label for="newpathCDB"><span class="req">*Path to Content Drive Folder</span></label><input name="request['+fields+'][Path to Content Drive Folder:]" type="text" id="npcdb'+fields+'" size="50" class="required"/><br /><small>Path of folder to be created on Content Drive (A: drive)<br><em>(example: A:\drivefolder</em></small><br /></div></p>';
```

I have tried multiple ways (jquery included) of getting the next div, pathCDB+fields, to show when the checkbox is checked. It works fine without the +fields in there... see http://jsfiddle.net/kuVzV/4/ however, when I add the fields it fails to show/hide with the checkbox.

When the form is created though, the div doesn't show at first, just like it shouldn't... so I know the ID is correct. According to Firebug it is showing the correct ID with the field showing the correct # that is create...

I am at a loss right now.

Any suggestions on how to show/hide this div if the checkbox is checked for multiple inputs created dynamically?

Comment: I found a <div> that needed to be </div> in my little snippit up there... that helps quite a bit. Thanks to @FERMIS for the help also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking out jQuery [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and Jquery [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbpathCDB1").on('click', $("#cbpathCDB1 input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked"), someFunction);

});
function someFunction(event){
    if (event.target.checked){
         $("#pathCDB1").hide('slow');
    }
    else{
       $("#pathCDB1").show('slow');
    }
}​
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FERMIS/7ThtT/6/ Here is an example with multiple fields.

Comment: The dynamic number being the id of the checkbox?

Comment: yes... It is created when the form is created. For example: var field=0; function addform(){ add my form here... ids look like: id="idname+'field'+"} so they are unique: idname0,idname1,idname2 depending on the form.

Comment: try using data-id="someNumberHere" then you can grab that number with jQuery $("#checkBoxId").data('id'); and I got a little bit of jQuery working for the show hide.

Comment: Try the jsfiddle in my answer, and is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, your code above is super close. When adding a second fieldset of inputs dynamically, the check box from the first fieldset get's unchecked. I'm looking into that now. Thanks for you time on this!